# Pattern to associate database model classes with their validation

Tags: java, validation

I'm currently trying to remove all business logic from our database model classes so they'll contain nothing more than fields, getters, and setters. Right now I'm a little bit stuck on how to extract the validation.

Our validation is fairly complex and each model would configure and run each of its validators itself when `isValid()` was called. I've extracted the validation of each model into its own parameterized validation class, where the parameter is the type of object it validates.

The problem I've had a hard time solving is coming up with a straightforward way to associate a model class with its validation class. The model classes are in a separate module from the validation because the validation is specifically for how we use those models in our application. That means my one restriction is that whatever design I come up with, it can't involve changing the model classes themselves.

I've tried out several designs, but right now I'm associating a model class with its validation class by manually adding them as key value pairs to a `Map`, then using a factory to return the correct validation for the type of object that's passed in. It works, but it's not very elegant and I have this feeling there's probably a better solution.

Here's how the model and validation classes are set up:

```
// Interface for all validation classes.
public interface Validation<T> {

    /**
     * Returns all validation for T.
     */
    Validator<T> getValidator();
}

// Concrete validation implementation.
public class FooValidation implements Validation<Foo> {

    public CompositeValidator<Foo> getValidator(Foo foo) {
        // CompositeValidator is a type of Validator that can contain and run many validators.
        return CompositeValidator.of(
            getFooValidatorA(foo),
            getFooValidatorB(foo),
            getFooValidatorC(foo)
        );
    }

    public Validator<Foo> getFooValidatorA(Foo foo) {
        return new FooValidatorA(foo);
    }

    public Validator<Foo> getFooValidatorB(Foo foo) {
        // Configure and return ValidatorB
    }

    public Validator<Foo> getFooValidatorC(Foo foo) {
        // Configure and return ValidatorC
    }
}

// Model class
public class Foo {
    public Integer id;
    public String name;
    public Bar bar;
    // etc...
}
```

In a nutshell, I want a straightforward way for the application to know that if I need to validate a `Foo` object, it should know that `FooValidation` is the validation class I need.

Comment: Any hints on what other designs you already thought about and/or tried?

Comment: The only other idea I tried implementing was creating a custom annotation that I could use to tag each validation class with the model class it could validate. The big advantage of this was that I could use reflection to automatically build all the model->validator class relationships and store them in a Map like I was doing above. The downside was that there was no type safety at compile time because and I couldn't figure out how to prevent a validator from being annotated incorrectly.